# for each value in dataframe column i wanna need to create values on another column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a data frame of many patients and their measurements in six hour, but for some patients not all the six hour  values have been recorded . 
I want for each subject-id , add values form 1 to 6 in hour column , and if the hour value already exist write it the same value, other wise leave it blank.
note (i will deal with this blank values using missing value techniques later.)

```
subject_id      hour        value
    2                 1           23
    2                 3           15
    2                 5           28
    2                 6           11
    3                 4           18
    3                 6           22
```

it is the out put i want to get

```
  subject_id      hour        value
        2                 1           23
        2                 2     
        2                 3           15
        2                 4
        2                 5           28
        2                 6           11
        3                 1            
        3                 2           
        3                 3           
        3                 4           18
        3                 5           
        3                 6           22
```

any one can help me how to make that
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['subject_id'].unique(), np.arange(1,7)],
                                  names=['subject_id','hour'])
df = df.set_index(['subject_id','hour']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df)
    subject_id  hour  value
0            2     1   23.0
1            2     2    NaN
2            2     3   15.0
3            2     4    NaN
4            2     5   28.0
5            2     6   11.0
6            3     1    NaN
7            3     2    NaN
8            3     3    NaN
9            3     4   18.0
10           3     5    NaN
11           3     6   22.0
```

Alternative is create all possible combinations by `product` and then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
from  itertools import product
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['subject_id'].unique(), np.arange(1,7))),
                                  columns=['subject_id','hour'])
df = df1.merge(df, how='left')
print (df)
    subject_id  hour  value
0            2     1   23.0
1            2     2    NaN
2            2     3   15.0
3            2     4    NaN
4            2     5   28.0
5            2     6   11.0
6            3     1    NaN
7            3     2    NaN
8            3     3    NaN
9            3     4   18.0
10           3     5    NaN
11           3     6   22.0
```

EDIT: If get error:

> cannot handle a non-unique multi-index

It means duplicated values per `subject_id` with `hour`.

```
print (df)
   subject_id  hour  value
0           2     1     23 <- duplicate 2, 1
1           2     1     50 <- duplicate 2, 1
2           2     3     15
3           2     5     28
4           2     6     11
5           3     4     18
6           3     6     22
```

Possible solution is aggregate `sum` or `mean` instead `set_index`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['subject_id'].unique(), np.arange(1,7)],
                                  names=['subject_id','hour'])
df1 = df.groupby(['subject_id','hour']).sum().reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df1)
    subject_id  hour  value
0            2     1   73.0
1            2     2    NaN
2            2     3   15.0
3            2     4    NaN
4            2     5   28.0
5            2     6   11.0
6            3     1    NaN
7            3     2    NaN
8            3     3    NaN
9            3     4   18.0
10           3     5    NaN
11           3     6   22.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(['subject_id','hour']).sum())
                 value
subject_id hour       
2          1        73
           3        15
           5        28
           6        11
3          4        18
           6        22
```

Or removed duplicates:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['subject_id'].unique(), np.arange(1,7)],
                                  names=['subject_id','hour'])
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['subject_id','hour'])
         .set_index(['subject_id','hour'])
         .reindex(mux)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
    subject_id  hour  value
0            2     1   23.0
1            2     2    NaN
2            2     3   15.0
3            2     4    NaN
4            2     5   28.0
5            2     6   11.0
6            3     1    NaN
7            3     2    NaN
8            3     3    NaN
9            3     4   18.0
10           3     5    NaN
11           3     6   22.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(['subject_id','hour']))
   subject_id  hour  value
0           2     1     23 <- duplicates are removed
2           2     3     15
3           2     5     28
4           2     6     11
5           3     4     18
6           3     6     22
```

Comment: sorry it worked with me in the example in question, but for my file in contain not unique values , so it gives me this error  **cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!** (because hour and subject_id some times repeated together , but with different values for each one , how can i deal with this problem  *

Comment: @Dr_noramahmoudDr_noramahmoud - Give me some time for solution.

Comment: @Dr_noramahmoudDr_noramahmoud - 2 possible solutions are added, please check it.

Comment: yes, it works ,,  we can also  use mean aggregate function instead of sum to make the solution more acceptable   *** thanks***

Comment: when i make re index , if it contain text columns , python removed it , how can i make re-index and put most frequent value for text columns